# Doctrine2 OneToMany without mappedBy

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have an entity 'listing' with OneToMany to entity 'view', the key between these to is view.content_id which holds the ID of listing, however, it also relates to other entities, so by adding

```
/**
 * @var Listing
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Acme\Bundle\Entity\Listing", inversedBy="views")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="content_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $listing;
```

To the view it brakes because when saving the view entity the content_id becomes null.

How can I fix it?

Relation on listing side:

```
/**
 * @var views
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Acme\Bundle\Entity\View", mappedBy="listing")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="content_id")
 * })
 */
private $views;
```

I'm making queries by joining the Listing.views and adding WITH content_type = :ContentType which discriminates some 'view' results.

Comment: The error you get doesn't tell you to use `cascade={"persist"}`?

Comment: There is no error, this is a valid approach. However, when saving 'view' the content_type field becomes null because there are two annotations pointing to this column.

Comment: Usually there's no need for second `JoinColumns` or `JoinColumn` annotation as there is one `owner` and one `inverse` side. My guess is that those annotation in your code are causing some kind of conflict so Doctrine cannot resolve which site is what...

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming pretty late to the party, but thought I would answer in case it helps someone else.

Because of the relation you've established between the two entities, you now have to assign an *object* to that property rather than the FK value itself. Like so:

```
$listing = $em->getRepository('Acme\Bundle\Entity\Listing')
              ->find($content_id);
$view->setListing($listing);
```

And not:

```
$view->setListing($content_id);
```

Of course, if it turned out to be something else, I'd be curious to know.

:^)

Comment: Unfortunately no. The solution was to use Inheritance Mapping/Discriminators.